# C++ project with Box2D compile with emscripten

Tags: box2d, emscripten

How can I compile the C++ project which uses Box2D with emscripten?

The problem: The Box2D library isn't in the [emscripten includes](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/tree/master/system/include).

How can I link this library to the emscripten?

Answer (score 0):

The Box2D files are in the [tests folder of emscripten](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/tree/master/tests/box2d/Box2D). Add this to your include path and then you can just include it like any other header.